# Cut out section of string

Tags: c, string, pointers

I wouldn't mind writing my own function to do this but I was wondering if there existed one in the string.h or if there was a standard way to do this.

```
char *string = "This is a string";

strcut(string, 4, 7);

printf("%s", string); // 'This a string'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Better write char string[] = "This is a string";  because you aren't allowed to modify string literals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use memmove to move the tail, then put '\0' at the new end position. Be careful not to use memcpy - its behaviour is undefined in this situation since source and destination  usually overlap.

Comment: Just allow memmove() to move extra byte with 0-terminator

Answer (score 4):

You can just tell [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) to cut the interesting parts out for you:

```
char *string = "This is a string";
printf("%.*s%s", 4, string, &string[7]); // 'This a string'
```

:-)

Comment: ... and then sprintf it into a new variable :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about getting rid of the middle of the string and moving the rest earlier in place, then I don't think there's a standard library function for it.

The best approach would be to find the end of the string, and then do an O(cut_size) cycle of shifting all the characters to the new location. In fact, there's a similar common interview question.

You have to be careful about using things like memory copy since the destination buffer overlaps with the source.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish what you want and avoid writing a new function with a combination of strncpy and strcat:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
  char   newStr[10];
  char   origStr[] = "This is a string";
  strncpy(newStr, origStr, 4);
  strcat(newStr, &origStr[7]);
  printf("newStr = %s\n", newStr);
  return(0);
}
```

For me, this outputs "This a string" (quotes mine), using Borland's free command line compiler on Windows XP.  You can check out string.h at: http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/string.h.html

Answer (score 0):

I already wrote the answer for a similar problem there https://stackoverflow.com/a/42283266/6003870. It suitable for common actions and based mainly the function **strncpy()** from the C standard library.
But this problem could be solved by the function **memmove()** as mentioned the dead user @sharptooth.

The function **str_slice_in_place()** use the **memmove()** as base and has support for positive indexes.

```
int
str_slice_in_place(char str[], const int index_from, const int index_to)
{
    // a support for only positive indexes
    if (index_from < 0 || index_to < 0)
        return -1;

    int len = index_to - index_from;

    // "index_from" is more than "index_to"
    if (len < 0)
        return -1;

    memmove(str, str + index_from, len);
    str[len] = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```

I also show you a code of a function **main()** and examples how to use this function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
    char line[] = "--------------------------------------";

    char str1[] = "Remember a good";
    char str2[] = "Remember a good";
    char str3[] = "Remember a good";
    char str4[] = "Remember a good";

    printf("|     Original     | Slice  | Result \n%s\n", line);

    printf("| %s | ", str1);
    str_slice_in_place(str1, 0, 8);
    printf("(%d, %d) | %s\n", 0, 8, str1);

    printf("| %s | ", str2);
    str_slice_in_place(str2, 3, 9);
    printf("(%d, %d) | %s\n", 3, 9, str2);

    printf("| %s | ", str3);
    str_slice_in_place(str3, 0, 1);
    printf("(%d, %d) | %s\n", 0, 1, str3);

    printf("| %s | ", str4);
    str_slice_in_place(str4, 1, 1);
    printf("(%d, %d) | %s\n", 1, 1, str4);

    puts(line);

    return 0;
}
```

---

### An output

```
|     Original     | Slice  | Result 
--------------------------------------
| Remember a good | (0, 8) | Remember
| Remember a good | (3, 9) | ember 
| Remember a good | (0, 1) | R
| Remember a good | (1, 1) | 
--------------------------------------
```

---

### A testing environment

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing this in C and know the offset then it's pretty simple.

```
char string[] = "my string";
char *substring;
substring = &string[2];

printf("%s", substring);
```

**EDIT:** If you wanted to shift the string.

```
char string[] = "my string";

int i = 0;
int offset = 2;

for( i = 0; string[i+offset] != '\0'; i++ ) {
 string[i] = string[i + offset];
}
string[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: I think he wants to eliminate parts of the middle of the string and move the rest to an earlier offset.

Comment: Sorry for missing that, seemed like you just wanted to print out a substring.